# How to specify the package name if multiple files exist in the package folder and one file contains the "package main"?

Tags: go

Suppose I have a package folder as below:

```
hello
  |---main.go
  |---utilities.go
```

In the `main.go`, I have:

```
package main
```

In the `utilities.go`, I have:

```
package hello
```

I did this because:

- I don't want to put all the utilities into the single `main.go` file.
- And the utilities are only used by this package so I don't want to put it out of the `hello` folder.

But when I run `go list hello`, it gives me this:

> can't load package: package hello: found packages main (main.go) and
>   hello (utilities.go) in E:\Workbench\Go\src\hello

Then I remove the `utilities.go` and tried the `go list hello` again with only `main.go`. It gives me this:

> hello

So do I have to move all the utilities to another package folder?

Do I have to keep only the single `main.go` in the hello package folder because it seems it doesn't get along well with other package names?

### ADD 1

An useful ref: http://thenewstack.io/understanding-golang-packages/

### ADD 2

After a few brief experiments, I guess the `import yyy` decides the link search path while the `package xxx` declaration decides the exported symbol name in the compiled `.a` file.

Because I noticed these facts:

- The `package xxx` declaration doesn't have to be the same as the containing package folder name, say `yyy`.
- But the `import yyy` declaration must use the package folder path `yyy`.
- When using a symbol from a package, we must still use the `xxx.Symbol` rather than `yyy.Symbol`.

### ADD 3

To confirm my guess in ADD 2, I did this:

(pkg1\file1.go)

```
package pkg2 // I deliberately use a different pkg name "pkg2" rather than the folder name "pkg1"

import "fmt"

func FA() {
    fmt.Println("in the pkg2.FA")
}
```

(cmd1\main.go)

```
package main

import "pkg1"

func main() {
    pkg2.FA() //here, the FA is referenced via "pkg2" rather than the "pkg1".
}
```

The above 2 files can compile and run.

But if I changed to this:

(cmd1\main.go)

```
package main

import "pkg1"

func main() {
    pkg1.FA() //here, the FA is referenced via "pkg1" as in the import statement. Should work, isn't it?
}
```

This will give:

> ....\src\cmd1\main.go:3: imported and not used: "pkg1" **as pkg2**
>
> ....\src\cmd1\main.go:6: undefined: pkg1 in pkg1.FA

And to double confirm, I checked the compiled `pkg1.a` file with `go tool nm pkg1.a`, **I didn't see package name affects the exported symbols**. (btw, the GNU nm tool seems not be able to recognize the golang `.a` file format.)

```
     U
 515 T %22%22.FA   <========== this is my fuction FA
 67b R %22%22.FA·f <========== this is my fuction FA
 5eb T %22%22.init
 67b B %22%22.initdone·
 683 R %22%22.init·f
     U fmt.Println
     U fmt.init
 673 R gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb
 66b R gclocals·69c1753bd5f81501d95132d08af04464
 65b R gclocals·e29b39dba2f7b47ee8f21f123fdd2633
 64d R go.string."in the pkg2.FA"
 63d R go.string.hdr."in the pkg2.FA"
 7d2 R go.typelink.*[1]interface {}
 796 R go.typelink.[1]interface {}
 737 R go.typelink.[]interface {}
     U runtime.algarray
     U runtime.convT2E
 6ec R runtime.gcbits.01
 68b R runtime.gcbits.03
     U runtime.morestack_noctxt
     U runtime.throwinit
 79a R type.*[1]interface {}
 7d6 R type..importpath.fmt.
 73b R type..namedata.*[1]interface {}.
 6ed R type..namedata.*[]interface {}.
 68c R type..namedata.*interface {}.
 74e R type.[1]interface {}
 6ff R type.[]interface {}
 69c R type.interface {}
     U type.string
```

So the conclusion so far is:

When the declared package name is **different** from the package folder name, package declaration will be used as an alternate name of the package.

Equivalent to this, but implicitly :

```
import pkg2 "pkg1"
```

And btw, since the package declaration is not reflected in the compiled `.a` file, I guess the golang compilation requires the presence of `.go` file.

Comment: See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: BTW: It is perfectly fine to keep utility functions in a file `utilities.go` and still under `package main`. Packages in Go typically consist of several files and often several type.

Answer (score 5):

go files in the same package AKA folder must have the same package name. The only exception are tests that can have a _test extension. The rule is 1 folder , 1 package therefore the same package name for all go files in the same folder.

The answer is yes , move the "hello" package files to their own folder or , use the same package name for all files in the same directory.

Comment: Do you actually mean move the "utilities.go" to another folder? It looks unwieldy to have a folder holding nothing but a `main.go` file.

Comment: utilities.go is not a package it's a file. what matters is the package name in the files , you just cannot have a "hello" and a "main" package in the same folder and build your code, that's all, this is not an opinion, this is how Go works.

Comment: I think I can put `package main` into the `utilities.go` and still keep it in the same folder as `main.go`. Go will still find the entry point by the name `main`.

Comment: It turns out the built-in `cmd\cgo` package does place `package main` for all the `*.go` files in the same package folder.

Comment: doesn't really change your issue. Only one package in one folder. I doesn't matter what the name of the package is. You can't have 2 packages in the same folder.